# Show that an element has order $2$ in $S_n$ if and only if its cycle decomposition is a product of commuting $2$-cycles.

Tags: symmetric-groups, proof-verification

In the Dummit-Foote text the algorithm for cycle decomposition is given as:[image]

> Based on the above algorithm the following exercise is asked to solve: **Show that an element has order $2$ in $S_n$ if and only if its cycle decomposition is a product of 
>   commuting $2$-cycles.**

*The problem, even though, is not hard to interpret, I still want it to leave for verification since the solutions of problems on symmetric group often contain less symbol and more word. Please have a look to the logic I used and comment on its validity*

My attempt:

**Lemma:** Cycle decomposition decomposes permutation into disjoint cycles: For otherwise, let the cycles $C_1,C_2$ have some element in common, x say. Let in course of the decomposition $C_1$ (whose first element is assumed to be $a$) is constructed earlier than $C_2$ (whose first element is assumed to be $b$). Then $x=\sigma^i(a)=\sigma^j(b)\implies\sigma^{i-j}(a)=b,$ a contradiction.

**Proof of the Exercise:** Let $\sigma\in S_n$ be such that $|\sigma|=2.$ Since $\sigma\ne1,$ the cycle decomposition of $\sigma$ must contain a cycle (of length greater than 1). If possible, let the decomposition of $\sigma$ contains a cycle of length $\ge3,$ say $(a_1~a_2~a_3~...).$ Then $\sigma^2(a_1)=a_3$ (by the construction of the algorithm) $\ne a_1,$ a contradiction to $\sigma^2=1.$ Thus cycle decomposition is a product of $2$-cycles and since they are disjoint (Ref: Lemma) they must be commuting.

*Conversely,* let $\sigma$ be such that it's cycle decomposition is a product of commuting $2$-cycles. Since those cycles appear due to cycle decomposition they must be mutually disjoint. Clearly $|\sigma|\ge2$ for otherwise $\sigma$ won't consider any $2$-cycle. Choose $x\in\{1,2,...,n\}.$

- If $x$ doesn't appear in any $2$-cycle $\sigma^2(x)=x.$
- If $x$ appears in any $2$-cycle $\sigma^2(x)=x$ (by the construction of the algorithm).

Thus $\sigma^2=1\implies|\sigma|=2.$

*Am I correct?*

Answer (score 2):

So all you need now is to show that any **cycle** can be written as the product of transposition...:

$$(i_1\,i_2\,\ldots\,i_n)=(i_2\,i_3)(i_3\,i_4)\cdot\ldots\cdot(i_{n-1}\,i_n)(i_n\,i_1)$$

Oberve that there are $\,n-1\,$ transpositions in the RHS above...

Comment: But the $2$-cycles in the RHS need not be commuting.

Comment: Yes, I know...so?

Comment: errr... why my solution is incomplete? Where should I insert that any cycle can be written as...

Comment: I really didn't read your whole solution: too long and complicated for me. What I remark is that if you *already* know that any permutation is the product of **disjoint** cycles and if you know that it is an *even* permutation iff the number of *even* cycles is even, then with what I wrote you're done...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Since we can decompose any permutation $\sigma$ into product of commuting cycles $c_i$:
$$\sigma=c_1c_2\cdots c_p$$
and suppose that the order of $c_i$ is $m_i$: $o(c_i)=m_i$ so prove that:
$$o(\sigma)=\mathrm{lcm}(m_1,\ldots,m_p)$$